# Can not see dll in msinfo32 "Loaded Module" section

Tags: windows

I use msinfo32 for getting the list of loaded module ("Lists all modules currently loaded into memory." - according to Microsoft documentation). But in this list I cannot find the DLL which was loaded by Internet Explorer process.

I can see this DLL using procexp.exe utility, but cannot see with msinfo32.

What is wrong with msinfo32 "Loaded Module" section?

Comment: Perhaps a 32/64-bit mismatch somewhere?

Comment: @Karan nope, all is 32-bit